Directed Acyclic Graphs equivalents
I am trying to understand how are equivalent DAGs created.
I am referring to the Richard McElrteth's "Statistical Rethinking (2n edition)" book. There is a practice exercise in chapter 5:

5H1. In the divorce example, suppose the DAG is: M → A → D. What are the implied conditional
independencies of the graph? Are the data consistent with it?

Implied conditional independency would be D _||_ M | A.
Jake Thompson's solutions to those exercises state that equivalent DAGs are:

M -> A -> D,
M <- A -> D and
M <- A <- D

My question - why is DAG M -> A <- D not equivalent to original DAG M -> A -> D? I understand that conditional independence (D _||_ M | A) has to be preserved, but if  M <- A -> D is considered equivalent (where M is not "connected" to D in any indirect way), why M -> A <- D is not?

It seems you're already clear that conditional independence (D _||_ M | A) is preserved under the DAG M <- A -> D, and conditional independence (D _||_ M | A) is not preserved under the collider DAG M -> A <- D, therefore these 2 DAGs are not equivalent relative to the original Markov DAG M -> A -> D which also preserves the same above conditional independence.
If you want to dig deeper to the non-equivalent collider DAG case, you can refer Berkson's paradox, while the first equivalent DAG doesn't exhibit such explaining away effect.
